# SUM of 2 aliases in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sum, alias, sql-server-2016-express

The `Balance` column shows current Stock on Hand + Open PO minus QTY Entered.

I have an existing query with ALIASes in the `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT dbo.Items.ItemNo, 
       dbo.Items.Name, 
       dbo.Vendors.Name AS VendorName, 
       ISNULL(ItemsStock.StockOnHand, 0) AS [Stock on Hand], 
       ISNULL(PO.[Open PO's'], 0) AS [Open PO], 
       ISNULL(WO.OpenWOQTY, 0) AS [QTY Entered].
```

How to add an additional column called `Balance` to sum Stock on Hand and Open PO then deduct QTY Entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT dbo.Items.ItemNo, 
       dbo.Items.Name, 
       dbo.Vendors.Name AS VendorName, 
       ISNULL(ItemsStock.StockOnHand, 0) AS [Stock on Hand], 
       ISNULL(PO.[Open PO's'], 0) AS [Open PO], 
       ISNULL(WO.OpenWOQTY, 0) AS [QTY Entered],
       ISNULL(ItemsStock.StockOnHand, 0) + ISNULL(PO.[Open PO's'], 0) - ISNULL(WO.OpenWOQTY, 0) AS [Balance]
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

Three suggestions:

1. Use table aliases.
2. Use `coalesce()` instead of `isnull()`.  `coalesce()` is ANSI standard.
3. Use column names that do not need to be escaped.

This looks like:

```
SELECT i.ItemNo, i.Name, v.Name AS VendorName, 
       COALESCE(is.StockOnHand, 0) AS Stock_on_Hand, 
       COALESCE(PO.[Open PO's'], 0) AS Open_PO, 
       COALESCE(WO.OpenWOQTY, 0) AS QTY_Entered,
       (COALESCE(is.StockOnHand, 0) + COALESCE(PO.[Open PO's'], 0) - COALESCE(WO.OpenWOQTY, 0) as Balance
FROM dbo.Items i JOIN
     dbo.Vendors v
     . . .
```

If you don't want to repeat the aliases, the traditional ways are to use a CTE or subquery.  SQL Server also offers lateral joins, introduced with the `apply` keyword:

```
SELECT i.ItemNo, i.Name, v.Name AS VendorName, 
       vals.Stock_on_Hand, vals.Open_PO, vals.QTY_Entered,
       (vals.Stock_on_Hand + vals.Open_PO - vals.QTY_Entered) as Balance
FROM dbo.Items i JOIN
     dbo.Vendors v
     . . . CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES ( COALESCE(is.StockOnHand, 0), COALESCE(PO.[Open PO's'], COALESCE(WO.OpenWOQTY, 0))
     ) vals(Stock_on_Hand, Open_PO, QTY_Entered);
```